# During SSL tunneling what IP address is seen by the destination server?

Tags: ssl, tunnel, tls

If I setup a SSL tunnel via a HTTPS proxy, what IP address will the destinations server see? Would it be the IP address of the client or the IP address of the proxy? Is there any point (e.g. during TLS handshake) when the the client's IP address is revealed to the destination server? Or is it always the proxy's IP address that is seen by the destination server at all times.

Answer (score 1):

> Would it be the IP address of the client or the IP address of the proxy?

This is similar to a VPN in that the IP address of the proxy exit is seen by the server.

> Is there any point (e.g. during TLS handshake) when the the client's IP address is revealed to the destination server?

The clients IP address is only seen by the proxy itself and not revealed to the destination server - unless the proxy explicitly does this for example with an `X-Forwarded-For` HTTP header.